# SQLAlchemy custom formula in sum()

Tags: sqlalchemy, window-functions

I have a table with columns: `a, b, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5` and need to apply a formula such as: `a * (x_i * (1 + (b / (1 - b)) ) + (y_i - x_i))` where `i = {1,2,3,4,5}`.

My problem is that I need to `sum()` the results of this formula partitioned w.r.t two the other columns `a, b`. So the select query will be like:

```
select(
    col_1,
    col_2,
    func.sum(
        a * (x_1 * (1 + (c / (1 - c)) ) + (y_1 - x_1))
    ).over(partition_by=[col_1, col_2]).label("sum1"),
    func.sum(
        a * (x_2 * (1 + (c / (1 - c)) ) + (y_2 - x_2))
    ).over(partition_by=[col_1, col_2]).label("sum2"),
    ...
    func.sum(
        a * (x_5 * (1 + (c / (1 - c)) ) + (y_5 - x_5))
    ).over(partition_by=[col_1, col_2]).label("sum5")
)
```

As you can see it is cumbersome to maintain and keep repeating the formula is error prone.

Is there a way to wrap this formula so that I can simply refer to formula like below or some way of abstracting it?

```
select(
    col_1,
    col_2,
    func.sum(my_custom_formula(a, b, x_1, y_1)).over(partition_by=[col_1, col_2]).label("sum1"),
    func.sum(my_custom_formula(a, b, x_2, y_2)).over(partition_by=[col_1, col_2]).label("sum2"),
    ...
    func.sum(my_custom_formula(a, b, x_5, y_5)).over(partition_by=[col_1, col_2]).label("sum5")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *hide* even more of the implementation detail if you want. The below should give you directional idea:

```
def get_expression(T: MyTable, pos: int, c):
    xn = getattr(T, f"x_{pos}")
    yn = getattr(T, f"y_{pos}")
    _expr = T.a * (xn * (1 + (c / (1 - c)) ) + (yn - xn))
    expr = func.sum(_expr).over(partition_by=[T.col_1, T.col_2]).label(f"sum{pos}")
    return expr

q = select(
    T.col_1,
    T.col_2,
    get_expression(T, 1, c),
    get_expression(T, 2, c),
    get_expression(T, 3, c),
    get_expression(T, 4, c),
    get_expression(T, 5, c),
)
```

Comment: thank you very much. This made things way more elegant.